# Trigonometric functions in ksqldb?

Tags: trigonometry, ksqldb

Hoping this is a dumb question and not a language limitation - but does anyone know how I can use trig functions in ksqldb queries? I need to calculate bearing between latitudes and longitudes, which doesn't seem to have a standard implementation. I can write the func myself no problem, but it requires sin, cos, and atan2, which I can't for the life of me find anywhere in the reference or defined keywords. Anyone know any tricks to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

As of ksqldb 0.23, there are no trig functions available.  (An entire list of functions is here: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/.

In terms of adding support, there are a few options.  If you are managing ksqldb yourself, you can add UDFs by following this guide: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/create-a-user-defined-function/.

If you are interested in contributing trig functions, let me know and we can work through that on GitHub!